# ajax GET request neihter success nor failure executing

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have the following ajax request:

```
function getDetails()
{
    $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'http://xxxxxx/get_determined_prize.php',
            success: function(result)
            {
                alert(result);
            },
            fail: function()
            {
                console.log("Failure!!");
            }
        });
}
```

which calls the following php file containing the following code:

```
<?php

    echo "5";
?>
```

can someone pinpoint what is the problem with my code? when i debugged the javascript method, during the execution of the ajax request, both the success and failure methods where skipped.

Comment: the ajax request gets fired? should be error instead of fail.

Comment: can u tell me if both files are on same server,means you are acessing your own url through ajax

Comment: @razhial when i look at the console the result is --
[13:41:44.869] GET http://localhost/get_determined_prize.php [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 2ms]

Comment: @developerCK one file is found on a wamp server while the other resides in my local system

Comment: php file is on remote server?

Comment: as developerCK stated, cross domain requests are turned off by default, so you have to check your server configuration. 
and your answer doesn't tell me if the ajax request gets fired or not ;)

Comment: @developerCK no the php file is found on a local server since im using WAMP

Comment: ok, so it is no more a cross domain request. check debug console in browser click on requested url , you will found header, request response etc. tell us what is there and also use error block in ajax and print object

Comment: @developerCK the request header contains the following : user agent, refere, origin, host connection, accept language. accept encoding and accept. While the respoinse conatins the X powered by, server, keep Alive, Date, content type, content length and connection.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the link and try this
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

```
  var request=  $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://url/get_determined_prize.php',
        success: function(result)
        {
            alert(result);
        }
    });

request.fail( function()
        {
            console.log("Failure!!");
        });
```

jqXHR.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {});
An alternative construct to the error callback option, the .fail() method replaces the deprecated .error() method. Refer to deferred.fail() for implementation details.